# Triggering an event when a new video starts while playing a YouTube playlist

Tags: javascript, html, playlist, youtube-javascript-api

I have a YouTube playlist; everything is working fine with that. Here's the code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var done = false;
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width: '100%',
            height: window.innerHeight-120+'px',
            vq: 'hd720',
            videoId: 'ZnToyoZus74',
            playerVars: {
                'autoplay': 1,
                'loop': 1,
                'showinfo': 0,
                'controls': 0,
                'playlist': [
                    'Glr36uh7Uls,Mx-cOLPqieg,C9uA-LFJS3Q,mKB4j3Lqa3w,tLmLXEShHT8'
                ]
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

However, I want to show customized information related to the currently playing video just below it (in a separated `<div>` but not overlaying the video). Once the video starts, a `<div>` containing the info from the first video will be displayed, once the video is over, this div will disappear. As soon as the second video start to play, then a different `<div>` containing the info for the second video will be displayed.

The `<div>` elements would contain an HTML file using the `id` of the video as the file name: `ZnToyoZus74.html`.

In this example I am using the following ids:

- `ZnToyoZus74`
- `Glr36uh7Uls`
- `Mx-cOLPqieg`
- `C9uA-LFJS3Q`
- `mKB4j3Lqa3w`
- `tLmLXEShHT8`

Comment: And how do you propose obtaining the next video's info? How are you attempting to show that?

Comment: The info for each video is in an html file (id of the video): 
ZnToyoZus74.html, 
Glr36uh7Uls.html, 
Mx-cOLPqieg.html, 
C9uA-LFJS3Q.html, 
mKB4j3Lqa3w.html, 
tLmLXEShHT8.html

Comment: Take a look at the [`onStateChange` event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Events).

Comment: SOLVED! I have to wait 5 hours to post the complete code. That's the price to pay to be a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

This is the final code, just in case someone is looking for the same answer:

```
<div id="player" style="float:right;"></div>
<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    width: '100%',
    height: window.innerHeight-110+'px',
    vq: 'hd720',
    videoId: 'K7XbJ0XLXPY',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'loop': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'controls': 0, 'playlist':['UiUZOo1b6m0,w0Sm9tRJDDA']},
    events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
        if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            var url = evt.target.getVideoUrl();
            var match = url.match(/[?&]v=([^&]+)/);
            var videoId = match[1];

            document.getElementById("myiframe").src='videosinfo/'+videoId+'.html';
        }
    }
</script>
<iframe  name="myiframe" id="myiframe" width="100%" height="200px" allowtransparency=true frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```